# Ho to update custom form component value programmatically in QWIK?

Tags: javascript, qwik, qwikjs

**Issue Description:**

In the `Counter` component, the displayed value of the input element updates correctly when using the +/- buttons. However, when submitting the form, the `field.value` for the corresponding form field remains the same as the default value and does not reflect the updated value.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Use the `Counter` component within a form.
2. Set an initial `value` (e.g., 99) for the `Counter`.
3. Click the "-" button to decrement the value.
4. Observe that the input field's displayed value updates correctly.
5. Submit the form.
6. Check the value of the `field.value` associated with the `Counter` component.
7. Observe that `field.value` remains the same as the default value (99), not reflecting the updated value.

**Expected Result:**

When submitting the form, the `field.value` should reflect the updated value of the `Counter` component, not the default value.

**Actual Result:**

The `field.value` associated with the `Counter` component retains the default value when submitting the form, even though the displayed value in the input field is correctly updated.

```
import { $, component$, useSignal } from '@builder.io/qwik';
import {routeLoader$, z } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";
import { useForm, type InitialValues, formAction$, zodForm$ } from "@modular-forms/qwik";
import type { SubmitHandler } from "@modular-forms/qwik";

interface CounterProps {
  name?: string;
  value?: number;
  attributes?: any
}

export const Counter = component$<CounterProps>((props) => {
  const { value = 0, attributes, name } = props;
  const count = useSignal<number>(value);

  const setValue = $((value: number) => {
    count.value = value;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick$={() => setValue(count.value - 1)}>
        -
      </button>
      <input
        type="number"
        name={name}
        value={count.value}
        {...attributes}
        onChange$={(e) => setValue(parseInt(e.target.value))}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick$={() => setValue(count.value + 1)}>
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

const formSchema = z.object({
  availability: z
    .object({
      daily: z.number().optional()
    })
    .optional()
});

type myForm = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;

export const useFormLoader = routeLoader$<InitialValues<myForm>>(() => ({
  availability: {
    daily: undefined
  }
}));

export const useFormAction = formAction$<myForm>(async (form) => {

  console.log('form: ', form);

}, zodForm$(formSchema));

export default component$(() => {

  const [, { Form, Field }] = useForm<myForm>({
    loader: useFormLoader(),
    action: useFormAction(),
    validate: zodForm$(formSchema),

  });

  const handleSubmit = $<SubmitHandler<myForm>>((values) => {
    console.log('handleSubmit.values: ', values);
  });

  return (
    <Form onSubmit$={handleSubmit}>
     {[
          'daily'
        ].map(name =>
          <Field key={availability-${name}-k} name={availability.${name as 'daily'}}>
          {(field, props) => (
            <Counter
                id ={availability-${name}}
                name ={availability.${name}}
                label ={${name} limit}
                value ={field.value}
                attributes ={props}
                error ={field.error}
            />
          )}
        </Field>
        )}
        <button type="submit" >
          SAVE 
        </button>
    </Form>
  );
});
```